# How to draw a circle with perspective transformation

Tags: matlab, image-processing, perspective

I want to draw a circle with perspective tansformation in Matlab. Here I have used sample of code to draw a circle. If I rotate this circle using perspective tansform this must be ellipse. I want to draw both axis rotation(X & Y) of a circle. Now I am struggled to draw a perspetive rotation of this circle.

I need to use  radious of the circle, x axis roation angle and y axis roation angle as input parameters.

```
Rimg = zeros(600,600);
ri = 100;
xcentre = 300;
ycentre = 300;

for r = 0:ri
    for rad = 0:(pi/720):(2*pi)
        xi = round(xcentre+(r*cos(rad)));
        yi = round(ycentre+(r*sin(rad)));
        Rimg(xi,yi) = 1;
    end
end

imshow(Rimg,[]);
```

The first image shows my circle and the second image shows the expected result. This is only rotated in x axis. But I need both axis rotation in a single image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Minor note: this is merely an affine transformation, not proper "perspective". A perspective transformation would display [foreshortening](http://www.brian-curtis.com/text/dfo_second_edition/powerslide14.html).

Comment: @Minor i dnot know exactly.i don't hav much exposure in this field.i want to simulate a car wheel rotation.normaly wheel having certain angle so that image will be an ellipse.